# I get an error "None of the input catalogs contained a matching launch image" in xCode5-iOS7

Tags: ios, xcode, launchimage

I'm trying to define launch images. Probably only one image is missing.

I'm following the instructions from this site [Create launch images in different sizes for different devices](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH22-SW1)

So I have 7 images with the required size.
But when I drag them to LaonchImages sheet it requires 8 images...the one that is missing is called "iPhone Portrait 2x" and according to the details pane I found its size 640x960 and I added it.

sill I'm getting the error - and the compilation fails...

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Select your project, go to Build Settings, search for AppIcon-2 and change it into AppIcon and you will be fine.

[image]

Comment: Hi, that worked for me thank you, but if I may ask (as I'm new to Xcode coming from Visual Studio) Why do we also have to change it here when we already mentioned it in the "General" tab? or at least shouldn't it change automatically?

Comment: @OmarBizreh i think xcode allows for multiple images assets for an app and it might be a silly bug by xcode.

Comment: I already have AppIcon in build settings.  This did not solve it.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me, I removed the launch screen from assets and it was giving me an error. Then I deleted the launch screen link from build settings.

Answer (score 25):

Select project file and then select target in question. In General tab there is in app icons and launch images launch image source should be "Use assets category" 
[image]

Comment: Thanks. I had to click into all three boxes shown until the value would switch back. But this was the required fix for me!

Comment: Thanks @Tr0yJ that was the case for me

Comment: My AppIcon is just red here. Mine is "Use Asset Catalog" already.

Answer (score 19):

My LaunchImage file had been deleted and I had to add a new one in my xcassets.

Go to your images.xcassets. If there is no LaunchImage listed on the left, click the plus button at the bottom and navigate to new iOS launch image.
[image]

Comment: Nailed it! Thank you.

Comment: Had a similar issue. Did same as suggested, but added New iOS App Icon, was missing for some reason

Comment: Now-days  this is deprecated...

Answer (score 17):

The `Launch Image` asset has been deprecated. I deleted the `Launch Image` asset but then I was getting compilation error.

In order to fix the error, the `Launch Image` asset catalog name has to be removed from Build Settings.[image]

Comment: THANK YOU. I spent DAYS googling to fix this crap...

Comment: Thanks man. I have been struggling with this issue from past 2 days

Answer (score 10):

I could solve this by going to **Build Settings** of my target, searching for word "launch", then removing (using Backspace) "Asset Catalog Launch Image Set Name", that was set to LaunchImage.

Comment: This was what I did when I switched from LaunchImage to LaunchScreen (storyboard).

Comment: Its very sad that you need to tell us all how to use xcode crappy interface by saying 'using backspace' - I spent 30 minutes trying to delete it 100 ways, but didn't try a simple backspace.

Comment: Actually OSX uses backspace (or CMD+backspace) in many places as a delete button, as Mac's keyboard doesn't have a DEL key.

Answer (score 5):

We had our **Asset Catalog Launch Image Set Name** set in our project target. After removing this from the *target* and instead setting it in our *project* it compiled fine.

Comment: In my case, I switched from a "launch image" to a "launch storyboard," but I got this error after removing the launch image. Removing the Asset Catalog Launch Image Set Name (or at least clearing its value) which had been set to the launch image name fixed the issue.

Comment: I upgraded to XCode 11.4/iOS 13. Since Launch Images are obsolete, I changed to using a Launch storyboard. I deleted the setting for `Asset Catalog Launch Image Set Name` and XCode found the storyboard that I created.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the problem was solved by **removing the reference to Images.xcassets and then add it to the project again**.

I'm not sure what caused the problem, but it may have something to do with the fact that I moved the assets "file" from one Xcode group to another, which would be weird as the file's path remained the same, but that was also the only thing I did with the file...

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem occurred when i have added a new watch target. Even though i had AppIcon set i was getting the error, i fixed it by removing the reference of asset catalog and added it back, you can do it by deleting the reference and add it back.

Answer (score 1):

This generally happens when you have accidentally deleted **Assets.xcassets**. You need to follow the below steps.

1. Right click on **Assets.xcassets** and select **Show File
   Inspector**.
2. Check if the desired target has been checked under
   **Target Membership**.
3. If its unchecked, Please select the target for which you need the
   Assets to be used.
4. Clean and Build the App.

Answer (score 0):

With xcode 11.3.1 you have to select the project file and after that, select the target in question, and in the General tab under "App Icons and Launch Images" select as shown bellow.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue using Flutter and IconKitchen for the icon. Make sure your icon assets are in the `ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset` directory. I also had to run `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` afterward.