# How to use UIImage in swift 3 the array comes nil?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiimage

I have one array of png images.

```
iconeImage = [UIImage(named:"ion-home")!,UIImage(named:"ms-medkit")!,UIImage(named:"ion-edit")!,UIImage(named:"ion-clipboard")!,UIImage(named:"ion-clipboard")!,UIImage(named:"ion-waterdrop")!,UIImage(named:"ion-calendar")!]
```

and I have one function for table-view which set the image with this array elements

here is the code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MenuTableViewCell") as! MenuTableViewCell
        cell.imgIcon.image = iconeImage[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
```

But it gives me error that iconeImage has nil values. so can you suggest me solutions. I am beginner in swift 3

Here is the screenshot
[image: a busy cat]
![two muppets][1]

Comment: Do you really have an image named `ion-home` in your project? Same for each one?

Comment: It seems like you don't actually have images matching all those image names or you might not be storing them in the correct place. Unless they are part of `Assets.xcassets`, you need to specify the extension in the image name as well.

Comment: If it says that `iconeImage` is `nil`, or that it has `0` images, it means that the code above has never been executed, or that the content was replaced in some other part. If on the other hand, one of the image inits should return nil, the app would crash saying that you had an unexpected nil (because of the forced unwrapps "!").

Comment: yes i have that images in my Assets.xcassets folder

Comment: Just for suggestion : Instead of Using Array of images why dont you just use Array of image name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what is the issue.

But when i have searching over stackoverflow. somewhere i have read that something problem with Assets.xcassets

then i got the error exact of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19511342/i-get-an-error-none-of-the-input-catalogs-contained-a-matching-launch-image-in)

And then solve the error with the help of that answer.

and hopefully i resolved the error.

meanwhile the problem is with assets folder.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of holding all images in memory I'd suggest you to store image names:

```
let iconImages = ["ion-home", "ms-medkit", "ion-edit", "ion-clipboard", "ion-waterdrop", "ion-calendar"]
```

And preload each image directly when you need it. It will not affect on performance as it is small icons. Also code will look cleaner.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MenuTableViewCell") as! MenuTableViewCell
    cell.imgIcon.image = UIImage(named: iconImages[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}
```

Double check if all the assets are added to your project. If they are there, image should be displayed.

Try to avoid of using implicitly unwrapped optional (!) in your code. Nil value will crash the app. In your example, imageView.image is an optional, so you can set UIImage(named: "imageName") to it.

Also, you can try to clean build folder, clean project and reinstall the app. Sometimes copying resources failed in Xcode.

Comment: check if Assets.xcassets added to your target. Open assets file, in the right menu tap on 1 tab. Check Target Membership section, there should be checkmark near name of your target

Answer (score 2):

Please try the below format

```
  let img = iconeImage[indexPath.row]
    if let imgData = img {
        cell.imgView.image = UIImage(data:imgData)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can store your image names instead:

```
let iconImageNames = ["ion-home","ms-medkit", ... , "ion-calendar")]
```

Later access them in your method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MenuTableViewCell") as! MenuTableViewCell
    let name = iconeImage[indexPath.row] ?? yourDefaultImageName
    cell.imgIcon.image = UIImage(named: name)
    return cell
}
```

As an example

Comment: @sanjayrathod, show me how your iconImage is defined

Comment: iconeImage = ["ion-home","ms-medkit","ion-edit","ion-clipboard","ion-clipboard","ion-waterdrop","ion-calendar"]

Comment: @sanjayrathod. it's not a definition; it's setting. where is your iconImage is defined?

Comment: var iconeImage:Array = [String]()

Comment: @sanjayrathod, where is your error now? if you're using string array

Comment: I am also thinking the same thing!!

because in assets folder images are exist.

but when i am trying to add the image with code i got this error.

also when i am trying to print the UIImage(named: name) then also i am  getting the same error.

Comment: @sanjayrathod, how is your yourDefaultImageName defined?

Comment: same error. When i am trying to add this code
cell.imgIcon.image = UIImage(named: name)
got the error. that is for nil

Comment: @sanjayrathod, try to put "" instead of yourDefaultImageName

Comment: with your suggestion i dont get any image]\

Comment: okay, now we definitely know, that you don't have these images in your project

Comment: @sanjayrathod, add to your question screenshot of your project folder with these images

Comment: Please check this image
https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/showImage?img_id=2725730

Comment: @sanjayrathod, I can't view it; why you don't add it to your question as a general image? not the link

Comment: Check now. i have uploaded the image now.

Comment: @sanjayrathod, provide images for 2x and 3x as well; you can use the same for now

Comment: i have placed images for all resolutions 1x,2x,3x.
but still not working

Comment: @sanjayrathod, check if your xcassets's target is right