# iOS AppIcon Issues

Tags: ios, icons

I'm having issues with importing my app icon and I can't find a solution that works for me anywhere.
I have my app icon in all sizes that could possibly be asked for, but no matter what I do I always get this error message

> None of the input catalogs contained a matching stickers icon set or
>   app icon set named  "AppIcon".

No matter what I do I get this error message: rename the asset folder to AppIcon (nah), create new folder named AppIcon and fill it again by hand (nope), delete both folders and create new one called MyIcon having filled it by hand again and changed Buildsettings to MyIcon in both general and buildsettings (try again), create a entirely new assets folder and put in a new file of AppIcon using the right click "new IOS App Icon" (haha no again). Each and every time the error message doesn't change and I have no clue what to do. I've checked almost every other thread about this issue and tried every solution but nothing has worked so far.

Any help would be immensely appreciated, this is the last step before I publish my app and I'm super infuriated by it

Comment: According to this link : https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7816 this is a known issue. Try adding an empty icon or refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19511342/i-get-an-error-none-of-the-input-catalogs-contained-a-matching-launch-image-in) for other solutions

Comment: I've seen both articles listed but am unsure what's exactly meant by an empty icon and am not experienced enough to understand the talk about pods in the initial link. I've tried every solution posted in the second link as well and am just really lost

Comment: You can checkout solution as provided in below link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27966247/asset-catalog-compiler-error-none-of-the-input-catalogs-contained-a-matching-a/28847041

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio edit your "info.plist" file.

Under **Visual Assets** and **App Icons**, make sure **Source** is pointing to "AppIcons" and not "None" or "(not set)"